# Solving set equation $X \cap A = X \cup A$ for $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to solve the following set equation: $X \cap A = X \cup A$ for $X$?

Intuitively it's obvious that it has to be $X = A$ but in class we solved it rigorously using de Morgan's rules.

We started from identity $(X \cup A)\cap(X \cup A)^c = \emptyset$, then we used the given equation to get $(X \cup A)\cap(X \cap A)^c = \emptyset$ and then we used de Morgan's rule: $(X \cup A)\cap(X^c \cup A^c) = \emptyset$.

And now I can't figure it out have we went from here to $(X\cap X^c)\cup(X \cap A^c)\cup(A \cap X^c)\cup(A \cap A^c) = \emptyset.$

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Simply use the distributivity of set algebras twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributivity $U \cap (V \cup W) = (U \cap V) \cup (V \cap W)$ with $U=X \cup A,$ $V=X^c$ and $W=A^c$ gives
$$
(X \cup A)\cap(X^c \cup A^c)
= ((X \cup A)\cap X^c) \cup ((X \cup A)\cap A^c).
$$

Then distributivity $(U \cup V) \cap W = (U \cap W) \cup (V \cap W)$ gives
$$(X \cup A)\cap X^c = (X \cap X^c) \cup (A \cap X^c)$$
and
$$(X \cup A)\cap A^c = (X \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap A^c).$$

Thus,
$$
(X \cup A)\cap(X^c \cup A^c)
= ((X \cap X^c) \cup (A \cap X^c)) \cup ((X \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap A^c)) \\
= (X \cap X^c) \cup (A \cap X^c) \cup (X \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap A^c).
$$

Answer (score 3):

Draw a Venn diagram, you can easily convince yourself this must be true.
To rigorously show $X=A$, we need to show $X\subset A$ and $A\subset X$. $X\subset X\cup A = X\cap A \subset A$, and the other direction follows similarly.

Comment: I convinced myself almost immidiately seeing equation. But I needed rigorous proof since I am freshman at Uni. Thanks. :)